# Phonegap loading all contacts is slow

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to load all device contacts and it is slow. Even a nexus 7 takes more time that is acceptable when loading all contacts (around 300). Is it supposed? Someone has the same problem? Any ideas?

I also thought of loading the contacts to the local storage on device ready. But I dislike this.

Comment: Hi did you end up solving this problem? I'm experiencing this too and have not figured out what's going on. This happens for both a custom cordova webview and a cordovaActvitiy.

Comment: @sub Hi, I set a minimum of three characters before doing search. It works really good this way.

Comment: Thanks for both your answers!

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by setting a minimum of three characters before the search. It works really good this way.

Comment: I'm sorry @AnkushThakur, it's been a while, I don't have it anymore.